# getting values from javascript to apex code

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code

I need to get a value from a javascript variable into a text field in a visualforce page.
I got it using a command button.But I was wondering if there is any other way of getting it,cz i dun want an onclick event.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell by your comment what event you're listening for, but assuming you know what that will be, just use document.getElementById() or a selector in jQuery to get the input field.  If you are using Apex:inputField, define the id attribute with something like 'theField'.  When the page is rendered, Salesforce should give an id attribute like 'j_id0:j_id1:theField' to the real  tag, but this can and probably will be different every time the page is viewed.  That means you're going to need to select the input by a substring.  Here's some sample code using jQuery (apologies to any jq gurus out there if it's inefficient-- feel free to improve).

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_1_6_1}"/>
    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('input[id*="theInput"]').val('Hello World');
        });
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputText value="{!phonenum}" id="theInput"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You could use ``input#theInput`` as selector which is much faster, especially since jQuery could then use ``querySelectorAll`` if available. Or does Apex wrap the id?

Comment: Not all VF tags have a wrapped id when rendered, but Apex:inputText does. You still need a 'contains' type of selector as in the code above that grabs it by a substring. So you'll have to make your id distinctive!

Comment: Ok, so your selector is fine. You could use ``.val('Hello World')``, though :)